# Speeding Up CSV Update/Import Into Django Model

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv, django-models

I have a large CSV file that I am importing into Django.  At the moment, if my math is correct, it will be done in 32 hours!  Is it possible to speed this up?

I have a CSV file with ~157,000 rows and 15 columns.  I am reading this into my Django model and saving it off to a MySQL database.  Here is where the magic happens:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    tmpRecord = Employee(
        emp_id = row[0], # Primary Key
        name = row[1],
        # snipped for brevity; other columns assigned
        group_abbr = row[14]
    )

    pieces = string.split(tmpRecord.name.title(), " ")
    newName = pieces[1]
    try:
        newName += " " + pieces[2]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    newName += " " + pieces[0]
    tmpRecord.name = newName

    tmpRecord.save()
```

The "pieces" chunk is taking the name field from "LASTNAME FIRSTNAME MIDDLE" and turning it into "Firstname Middle Lastname".

This will be run about once a month to update the database with new employees and any changes to existing employee records.  Much of the time, an existing record isn't going to change, but any one (or more) of fields might change.  Is there a check I could add that take less time then just calling `save()` on each record?

At the moment, this is taking about 15 seconds per 20 records to complete!  Is there a way I can speed this up (substantially)?

**UPDATE:**

If it matters, the `emp_id` is the table's primary key.  No employee ever has the same id as a previous employee (retired employees included).

Comment: You probably want to add the `@commit_on_success` decorator to avoid the database doing an implicit database commit after each `.save()`. That'll probably help. (Especially if using InnoDB.)

Comment: In addition, `string.split` has been deprecated for a long while. Try something like `pieces = tmpRecord.name.title().split(); tmpRecord.name = " ".join((pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[0]))` for a Pythonic approach.

Comment: The `@commit_on_success` would go just above the function `def`?

Comment: Can you please share the code you used to prepare the intermediate load CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use your python script to prepare an intermediate load CSV, then try doing a load operation instead?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

Comment: This is the route I've ultimately gone.  Reading, modifying and writing the CSV for a MySQL import is very appropriate for speed.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think bulk_create will help you
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create

If you have problems with data that already persist in database. Insert into other table, then using SQL queries fix your issue.

Comment: Would the `bulk_create` fail if I try to run it with records that already exist?

Comment: If you violate id or unique constraint it must fail. It may depend on your database backend - not sure about sqlite. But my opinion is when you manually set id you don't want to lose control of what is happening. So use other empty table and then SELECT INSERT to merge data in database.